# Randomly freeze when play video with sound

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, freeze, video-streaming

When I play video with sound on, computer often turn to freeze immediately, but if i play video without sound, everything when normal. I'm using NVIDIA GeForce GTX 650, ram 8gb, Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4440 CPU @ 3.10GHz.

This is log from journalctl -b-1

```
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:01:00: GPU-905179a7-c314-5633-72d0-2751abc5bdf3
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 79, pid=1769, GPU has fallen off the bus.
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: GPU has fallen off the bus.
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: NVRM: A GPU crash dump has been created. If possible, please run
                                       NVRM: nvidia-bug-report.sh as root to collect this data before
                                       NVRM: the NVIDIA kernel module is unloaded.
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: irq 16: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: CPU: 2 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/2 Tainted: P           OE     5.13.0-41-generic #46~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. H81M-DS2/H81M-DS2, BIOS FC 01/20/2014
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: Call Trace:
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  <IRQ>
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  dump_stack+0x7d/0x9c
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  __report_bad_irq+0x3a/0xaf
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  note_interrupt.cold+0xb/0x60
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  handle_irq_event_percpu+0x73/0x80
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  handle_irq_event+0x3b/0x60
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  handle_fasteoi_irq+0x9c/0x150
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  __common_interrupt+0x43/0xa0
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  common_interrupt+0x85/0xa0
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  </IRQ>
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  <TASK>
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  asm_common_interrupt+0x1e/0x40
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: RIP: 0010:poll_idle+0x69/0xbb
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: Code: f0 41 80 4f 02 20 49 8b 07 a8 08 75 3b 4c 89 ef 4c 89 e6 e8 09 85 d5 ff 49 89 c5 b8 c9 00 00 00 49 8b 17 83 e2 08 75 20 f3 90 <83> e8 01 75 f1 65 8b 3d 63 09>
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffaacfc00afe10 EFLAGS: 00000246
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: RAX: 000000000000003a RBX: 000004738eaa4e52 RCX: 000000000000001f
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 000000002962cdac RDI: fffffffd5d5e348e
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: RBP: ffffaacfc00afe38 R08: 000004738eaa6d05 R09: ffffffffadc50e60
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: R10: ffff99ac67333864 R11: ffff99ac67333844 R12: ffff99ac67340b00
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: R13: 0000000000004e20 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff99ab40a3b080
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  cpuidle_enter_state+0x8d/0x360
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  cpuidle_enter+0x2e/0x40
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  call_cpuidle+0x23/0x40
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  do_idle+0x1e6/0x260
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  cpu_startup_entry+0x20/0x30
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  start_secondary+0x11f/0x160
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xc2/0xcb
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel:  </TASK>
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: handlers:
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: [<0000000052fa2d23>] usb_hcd_irq
Mei 22 14:59:15 coding-desktop kernel: Disabling IRQ #16
```

As far as I read, Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 79, pid=1769, GPU has fallen off the bus could be caused by many thing. Any help will be appreciated

free -h result

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7,7Gi       2,0Gi       3,6Gi        70Mi       2,1Gi       5,4Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi          0B       2,0Gi
```

sysctl vm.swappiness result:
vm.swappiness = 60

swapon -s result:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        2097148 0   -2
```

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 as my operation system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a very old BIOS, and need to update first. Then, if that does not fix the problem, we can troubleshoot further.

```
Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. H81M-DS2, BIOS FC 01/20/2014
```

There are 5 revisions of this motherboard, and I suspect that you have revision 2.0, so the BIOS update page is [here](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H81M-DS2-rev-20/support#support-dl-bios). Amongst other fixes, this fixes "Support New 4th Generation Intel Core Processors", which is what you have... Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4440 CPU.

**Note**: Confirm that you have a revision 2.0 motherboard

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS

**Update #1:**

In the `terminal`...

Let's increase your /swapfile from 2G to 4G.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
head -c 4G /dev/zero | sudo tee /swapfile  # create a new /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines are present.

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Comment: ok, let me try first, thank you

Comment: @RusdiToriq Status please...

Comment: I confirm my motherboard is revision 2.0. I try upgrade bios from version fc to fj using q-flash. After update, the problem no longer occurred. Thank you for your solution

Comment: @RusdiToriq Great news! Thanks for the update.

Comment: the problem occured again, so i guees, the cause is not (only) bios version, still inverstigating

Comment: @RusdiToriq Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s`. Is this a desktop computer? If so, re-seat the Nvidia in its slot.

Comment: @RusdiToriq Please see Update #1 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: i already re slot my vga, buat it doesn't work, recently my pc unable to boot, it keep restarting during booting, turn out, one of my ram is broken. so now I change my ram. so far i have no problem play video, i guess the main cause is the ram

Comment: so far i still dont know root cause of this issue, but if i turn on my computer, turn on my speaker, plugout sound cord, and plugin back, i able to play video with sound without any issue

Comment: @RusdiToriq What version Ubuntu? Did you replace your bad RAM? Did you run `memtest`?